# Reverse word letters in a sentence java

Tags: java, string, reverse

For my program I want to reverse letters in a line of text. However I don't want to reverse the order of the words in the sentence. 
For example when I input: "This is a string"

I get: gnirts a si siht

But I want: siht si a gnirts

```
public static String reverseWordCharacters(String text1) {
        String reverse = "";
        int length = text1.length();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse = reverse + text1.charAt(i);
            System.out.println();
        }
        return reverse;
    }

}
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Smells like homework with those restrictions.....

Comment: Exactly that is why I provided what I have done so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String sentence = "This is a string";
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
String invertedSentece = "";
for (String word : words){
    String invertedWord = "";
    for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        invertedWord += word.charAt(i);
    invertedSentece += invertedWord;
    invertedSentece += " ";
}
invertedSentece.trim();
```

Comment: For long sentences/inputs, a `StringBuffer` would be more appropriate for `invertedSentence`. Also look at StringUtils for reversing strings.

Comment: Beware though: This code only works iff you have no multi-codepoint letters. If you have, hilarity ensues.

Answer (score 1):

Commons Lang's StringUtils class has method to do this:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#reverse(java.lang.String)

Comment: it's not the solution to the question, take a look on the desired output

Comment: split it on spaces and then use StringUtils.reverse() on each element then concatenate back together.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the easiest way

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseString{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter any Sentence: ");
    String sentence = sc.nextLine();
    String[] stringArray = sentence.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i<stringArray.length; i++){
        String temp = new StringBuilder(stringArray[i]).reverse().toString();
        System.out.print(temp+" ");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String revWrord(String s) {
       LinkedList word = new LinkedList();
       Scanner scanfs = new Scanner(s);

        while(scanfs.hasNext()) {
            word.add(scanfs.next());
        }

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

        while(true) {
            temp.append(word.poll()).reverse();
            output.append(temp);
            temp.delete(0,temp.length() );

            if(word.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            } else {
                output.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: After receiving a sentence I separate the word and put it in linkedlist as queue. 
Then Take out that word and reverse, after that append that in output to build that sentence again but in reverse word. 
like
input:     I Love Bangladesh.
output:   I evoL hsedalgnaB

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s= "This is a string";
System.out.println(s);
String finalrevresestring = "";
String wordreverse = "";
String[] a = s.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i<=a.length-1; i++) {
    for (int x=a[i].length()-1; x>=0; x--) {
        wordreverse += a[i].charAt(x);
    }
    finalrevresestring += wordreverse;
    finalrevresestring += " ";
    wordreverse = "";
    }
System.out.println("This is reverse: "+finalrevresestring);
}
```

Comment: Some text explaining your answer so people can see why it is a better answer and give it a vote would be helpful. Code only answers are not always good enough. Please use the [edit] button to improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
        String sentence="This is String";
        String[] words=sentence.split(" ");
        String inverted=" ";
        for(String eachWord : words){           
            for(int i=0;i<eachWord.length();i++){
                inverted+=eachWord.charAt(eachWord.length()-1-i);
            }
            inverted+=" ";
}
        System.out.println("Inverted words in the given sentence is :"+inverted);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer("I live in India");
int i=0,j=0,w=0;
//w is first position of word
//j is last position of word

while(i<s.lenght){

if(s.charAt[i]==" "||i==s.lenght()-1)
{
j=i;
if(i==s.length-1)
j=i;
else
j--;

swapMethod(w,j);
w=i+1;
}
i++;
}
```

Comment: I was going to improve the code whitespace but you haven't even spelled `length` properly, so this doesn't even compile.